# How to Combine 2 .hex to one

Tags: disassembly

I have a Ensoniq Synthesizer with broken buttons,my idea is to simulate the input over sysex. Unfortunately the sysex exclusive is set off by default.

There are 2 ROM files `upper.bin` and `lower.bin` coded for M68000 so first I need to bring this to together to decompile and trying to reverse engineer.

But how do I combine those to be the complete 16 bit code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python like this:

```
filename_upper = 'upper.bin'
filename_lower = 'lower.bin'
filename_out = 'merge16b.hex'

concat_bytes = bytearray()
#nbBytes=4 # Take 32 bits in each input file to get 64 bits in the output file
#nbBytes=2 # Take 16 bits in each input file to get 32 bits in the output file
nbBytes=1  # Take 8 bits in each input file to get 16 bits in the output file

with open(filename_upper, 'rb') as f_upper, open(filename_lower, 'rb') as f_lower:
    content_upper = f_upper.read()
    content_lower = f_lower.read()

    for i in range(0,len(content_upper),nbBytes):
        concat_bytes+=content_upper[slice(i,i+nbBytes)]
        concat_bytes+=content_lower[slice(i,i+nbBytes)]

with open(filename_out, "wb") as binary_file:
    # Write bytes to file
    binary_file.write(concat_bytes)
```